# getting "syntax error, unexpected ','" for a function declaration

Tags: php, function

I am getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /xxx/login.php on line 28
```

the function is defined as :

```
function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember, $fb = 0){
//something here
}
```

and I am calling it like :

```
$retval = $session->login($fbuserid, , , 1);
```

I have been working on this for over 2 hours, and I just got this error, so I dont know how complex of an error it is as I just cant see anything wrong with the code!!!

Comment: Where did you see that you can just omit parameters like that when calling a function?

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was an honest mistake, do you guys honestly think I deserve all these negative votes?? lool

Comment: Your question isn't helpful or interesting. It's a mere parse error, something you could have (should have) resolved on your own. It's not really helpful if people resolve parse errors all day long, that's the easiest error that can be solved in programming. You should strive to solve parse errors on your own. I've never seen a language where you can omit parameters like you did to be honest, so yes, you kind of did deserve negative votes.

Comment: its a mistake that you might make after programming for 2-3 hours straight, no one is perfect and this site is suppose to help others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `null` if you want to skip a parameter. You can't just leave it blank. Only `list` support that, and that only because it's a construct and not a function.